# Raspberry Pi Pico and error message "ImportError: no module named 'machine'"

Tags: python, raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit-circuitpython

I am running the following blink program on my [Raspberry Pi Pico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Raspberry_Pi_Pico). I am using [CircuitPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CircuitPython).

```
from machine import Pin
import time

led = Pin(13, Pin.OUT)
while True:
    led(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    led(0)
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I run it though, it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: no module named 'machine'
```

I have tried to find if I need to download a library file or anything about the machine module, but I haven't found anything. Why can't it find the machine module?

Comment: Have you tried to install micropython following the steps on their official GitHub? https://github.com/micropython/micropython

Comment: I just put the circuit python uf2 file on to the pico. I am using mu editor with circuit python mode. I have not used their github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is for [MicroPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroPython). [CircuitPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CircuitPython) is different. See *[CircuitPython Digital In & Out](https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-essentials/circuitpython-digital-in-out)*.

```
from digitalio import DigitalInOut, Direction, Pull

led = DigitalInOut(board.LED)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and a search found this question.
I changed the *Interpreter setting* in Thonny (under options) from *Local Python 3* to *MicroPython* ([Raspberry Pi Pico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Raspberry_Pi_Pico)).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the incorrect uf2 file as the official (stable) version is not out as of writing this.
In order to check this, type the following in MircoPython's command line:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.implementation
(name='micropython', version=(1, 19, 1), _machine='Raspberry Pi Pico with RP2040', _mpy=4102)
```

If the response shows "Pico" and not "Pico W" then copy the latest version from [here](https://micropython.org/download/rp2-pico-w/) and copy it onto your [Pico W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Raspberry_Pi_Pico) (in USB mode).